# Sparql query on DbPedia return not repeated objects

Tags: python, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I'm trying to execute this Sparql query on the [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) but it seems to ignore the *DISTINCT*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?source ?title ?content ?topic
            WHERE {
                ?source rdfs:label ?title ;
                <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?content ;
                foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?topic .
                ?title bif:contains "php" .
}
```

In fact if you try to run the query the result is something like this:

[image]

I am running the query from a python file with this code returning a json:

```
query_rdf = ""
query_rdf += '''
              SELECT DISTINCT ?source ?title ?content ?topic
                WHERE {
                        ?source rdfs:label ?title ;
                        <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?content ;
                        foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?topic .
                        ?title bif:contains "php" . 
                }
        '''      
__3store = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql"       
sparql = SPARQLWrapper (__3store,returnFormat="json")
sparql.setQuery(query_rdf)
result = sparql.query().convert()
print json.dumps(result, separators=(',',':'))
```

Comment: What results are you *trying* to get?  The query is working as it should. If there are, e.g., 2 labels (one in each of two different languages) and 2 abstracts (one in each of two different languages) then there are 4 distinct combinations of label and abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DISTINCT keyword means that each *row*, as a whole, is distinct from the rest.  In the results you're showing, I see labels and abstracts in English (en), Spanish (es), and Arabic (ar).  If you have data like:

```
:a rdfs:label "..."@en, "..."@es ;
   dbpedia-owl:abstract "..."@en, "..."@es ;
   foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf :aa .
```

and you run a query

```sql
select distinct ?source ?label ?abstract ?topic where {
  ?source rdfs:label ?label ;
          dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
          foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?topic
}
```

you will get four rows in your results, because there are four distinct combinations:

> 1 source × 2 labels × 2 abstracts × 1 topic = 4 rows

If you want to restrict the label and abstract to a single language (e.g., English), then you just need to filter the results.  E.g.:

```sql
select distinct ?source ?label ?abstract ?topic where {
  ?source rdfs:label ?label ;
          dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
          foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?topic .
          ?label bif:contains "php" . 
  filter( langMatches(lang(?label),"en")
          && langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en") )
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fsource%20%3Flabel%20%3Fabstract%20%3Ftopic%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fsource%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf%20%3Ftopic%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Flabel%20bif%3Acontains%20%22php%22%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Yes, but it's the same resource. How can I specify for example to only show results in english, with _@en_

Comment: Yeah man!! Exactly what I wanted to do, but I'm very noob with sparql and dbpedia. Thank you very much!